# What is the time window for Kafka JMX metrics?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, jmx, kafka-producer-api

The documentation on some JMX metrics mentions a time window on which some of the metrics are averaged.

For example here: https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/monitoring.html

What is this time window? Is it fixed, configurable, or is it dynamically adjusted?

```
request-size-avg::
    The average size of all requests in the window for a broker.
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

request-size-avg is a metric computed from kafka-clients (producer/consumer).
The window is configurable via the config : `metrics.sample.window.ms`

From the official [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs) :

```
The window of time a metrics sample is computed over.
```

The value for this config is setted to 30000 (30 seconds) by default.
This config is currently supported by Consumer, Producer, Kafka Connect and Kafka Streams.

Note that additional configs may influenced metrics computation : `metrics.num.samples`

Comment: Note that this is not the time window the metric is computed over, but the window for _one sample_ of the rolling set of samples used to compute the metric. The number of samples is configurable. So if the window is 30s, and the number of samples is 10, then the metric is actually calculated over a period of ~300s. This period is not exact since the current window may not represent the full window time, so really it's calculated over something like 270s < period < 300s seconds at any point in time.